# What to use to do dynamic searches on Mysql in Spring Boot app?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

I will be using Spring Boot 3.2.2 + Java 21 as a given.

I have a Mysql database with non-trivial objects. For example, a simplified example, let's say:

```
Film
  Actor[]
```

I know I can do this with a JpaRepository using findAll() and use Hibernate to do the full Pojo mappings, but ...

- Name derived queries won't work since the search criteria will be dynamic based on the REST request
- I was originally planning to use Webflux and r2dbc, but looks like you can't use Hibernate with r2dbc and then you have to do all the mappings to the POJOs manually?
- I came across QueryDSL and have used it before on Mongo, looks like you can't use that in Webflux either? Does that do all the nested mappings for you?

Basically, I trying to see if there is anything that can do dynamic queries and nested mappings out of the box? :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use findAll() with specification and pageable.
Within your specification class you can use CriteriaBuilder to create dynamic queries. And let pageable handle page number, page size and sorting. This approach can handle pretty much any scenario.

If the database table you are filtering and sorting on is just one set table then you can skip using the findAll() method and just go for a criteria builder solution.

Comment: hmm... interesting. So basically use Hibernate @JoinTable on the FilmTable as I do now and just do the findAll() with the specification and it will do all the nested table population? Would this approach support something like "give me all the films with Tom Hanks in them? In raw SQL that would be an inner join and the where clause on the child table.

Comment: If you define an inheritance strategy of @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED) on your entity it will automatically do a sql join query when you use the findAll() method. and It will also support joins in your entity that have for example "@oneToMany or @oneToOne" annotations on them, but in these cases you will need to define the joins a in criteria builder to filter on them.
So the short answer is yes, it will support the joins and you can filter and sort on child table values.